# how to retopo a model with a given verts number

Tags: modeling, python

I am new to Blender 3d so I have a question about retopo

I want to retopo a model and let it have a given verts number,and
Number according to certain rules

I use QuadRemesher now.it can set a certain quadrilaterals number but the all number of face is indeterminacy

if there is any addons or some operation can help？